# How could I change the properties of a Control after the resource file has been applied?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

I need to add a scroll bar for a component when a user changes their font size to 125% or 150%. To do this I added a method in the component, which sets the AutoScroll property to true.

```
protected override void OnSizeChanged(EventArgs e)
{
    if (SystemFonts.DefaultFont.Size < 8)
    {
        this.AutoScroll = true;
    }
    if (this.Handle != null)
    {
        this.BeginInvoke((MethodInvoker) delegate
        {
            base.OnSizeChanged(e);
        });
    }
}
```

This works well, but one of the components should not get a scrollbar.

The above method will be triggered when initializing the controllers like this:

```
this.ultraExpandableGroupBoxPanel1.Controls.Add(this.pnlViewMode);
this.ultraExpandableGroupBoxPanel1.Controls.Add(this.ucASNSearchCriteria);
resources.ApplyResources(this.ultraExpandableGroupBoxPanel1, "ultraExpandableGroupBoxPanel1");
this.ultraExpandableGroupBoxPanel1.Name = "ultraExpandableGroupBoxPanel1";
```

The method will be triggered when adding into Controls and after this, the  resource will be applied. The component which I don't want to change belongs to `ucASNSearchCriteria` in above code.

Now I want to set the `AutoScroll` property of 'ucASNSearchCriteria' to false after the resource has been applied. I have little knowledge about the rendering process of c# ui controls. Is it possible to dynamically change properties after applying?

Comment: Can't you just do ucASNSearchCriteria.AutoScroll = false;

Comment: You don't need to put "this" every time by the way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd create a derived control of the desired type and add a property `AllowAutoScroll` or anything like that with the default value `true`.

With this, you can change that property in the WinForms designer easily and react on that property as the size gets changed.

So the designer will add this line of code for you if you change it to be non-default (`false`):

```
this.ucASNSearchCriteria.AllowAutoScroll = false;
```

... and you can react on that new property like this:

```
protected override void OnSizeChanged(EventArgs e)
{
    if (AllowAutoScroll)
    {
        if (SystemFonts.DefaultFont.Size < 8)
        {
            this.AutoScroll = true;
        }
        if (this.Handle != null)
        {
            this.BeginInvoke((MethodInvoker) delegate
            {
                base.OnSizeChanged(e);
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: sorry that didn't log on recently, thanks for your help!